# CSS columns breaking when printing

Tags: html, safari, webkit, css

```
.class {    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-gap: 0.25in;
    -webkit-column-rule-width : 1px;
    -webkit-column-rule-style : solid;
    -webkit-column-rule-color : #eee;
}
```

So it works perfectly in Safari, but when printing, the 4 columns turn into a single column spanning multiple pages. Any ideas?

Comment: This is very frustrating.  I've been working on a solution for a few hours now and it looks like I'll have to take a different route entirely.  The WebKit implementation (including the latest build, which I just checked, Chrome and wkhtmltopdf) have CSS3 columns turned off (see Peter's answer).  Firefox actually renders them correctly, but I have no idea how to access that efficiently programatically :-(  Bad times.

Comment: Related Chromium bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=99358

Answer (score 33):

It seems like the developer of columns in Webkit (Dave Hyatt) disabled columns when printing, because he couldn't implement page breaking properly: https://www.webkit.org/blog/88/css3-multi-column-support/#comment-16854

I'm surprised that in more than 5 years, no solution has been found...

Comment: That's very interesting because I've run into a similar problem that I'll have to end up implementing as a custom solution. It's pretty annoying there is not a solution yet.

Comment: In the conversation it seems the developers are indicating that is fixed but I'm still seeing the issue.

Comment: this bug was recently fixed in chome - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=99358

Comment: This is fixed in Chrome, not in Safari.

Comment: it's fixed in Safari, but when I tried to print on iOS WKWebView, the errors shows up again

Comment: How is this still not fixed over a decade later???!!!

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting that in Firefox 31.0 on OSX these do print correctly with the below style. However it's still broken in WebKit (safari/chrome).

```
.column_wrapper {
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working in chrome, firefox. you have only one temporary solution. use IE for multi column print

Comment: Works like a charm in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to print in columns is to print with FireFox or IE... and use the un-browser prefixed versions so that FF nad IE can read the columns CSS

Answer (score -1):

the print and web page are 2 different things. So try to use diff css for print pages and try to see

> page-break css properties. it will come in handy

---

Comment: it would be very nice if you had post and example!