# why selector of @media print is not displaying correct format when i click print button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

### when i click print button, text is suppose to show in four column in print dialog but it shows  as a paragraphs as i wrote it.

```js
This are my script code where there is click event of print button. 
when i click it print dialog popup but the text which it suppose to 
show in four column shows it as a paragraphs.

 <script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(document.body).on('click', '#btnPrint', function () {
         
         
            window.print();
           
            
           
        });
    });


</script>
```

```css
my css code.



@media print {
   
 .FourColumnClass
    {
    -webkit-column-count: 4; 
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;

    -webkit-column-gap: 40px; 
    -moz-column-gap: 40px;
    column-gap: 40px;
    }

}
```

```html
my html code.

<div class="clsbtn">
    <button type="button" id="btnPrint">Print</button>
</div>

<div class="FourColumnClass">
  my dog name is jonney. my dog name is jonney. my dog name is jonney.
  my dog name is jonney. my dog name is jonney. my dog name is jonney. 
  my dog name is jonney. my dog name is jonney. my dog name is jonney. my   dog name is jonney.
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like a Chrome bug. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26718362/4402222 and https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=99358

Answer (score 0):

Add `media="print"` in your `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css" media="print">` on html head