# CSS: @media print & column-count not working at all

Tags: css, media-queries, column-count

I have a div with three vertical divs in it. Within these inner divs there are divs with the column-count CSS property (working well, see below).

The working part is this (for multiple sreen sizes) as an example:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1100px) {
.masonry {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
}
}
```

Could someone please tell me why the following code is not working when I try to print a page?

```
@media print {
.masonry {
    -moz-column-count: 2 !important;
    -webkit-column-count: 2 !important;
    column-count: 2 !important;
}
}
```

The @media print query is working with

```
@media print {
    body {
    display: none;
    }
}
```

for example.

I tried Safari and FF on Mac OS X.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's a known bug in Chrome

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=99358

This link can be usefull for you:

[CSS columns breaking when printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738908/css-columns-breaking-when-printing)

This is a small refference that one user try:

http://blog.pdark.de/2010/11/19/printing-web-pages/

Good luck

Comment: But I didn't use Chrome?

Comment: However you need to change the behaviour from flexbox to other technology (displays, tables, etc), to make it runs in printing.